# Registering new users via OAuth2 : what to set as user identifier for future log ins?

Tags: symfony, authentication, oauth-2.0, fosuserbundle, hwioauthbundle

I have managed to successfully configure [this](https://gist.github.com/danvbe/4476697). The problem is, when I change the lines below :

```
//I have set all requested data with the user's username
//modify here with relevant data
$user->setUsername($username);
$user->setEmail($username);
$user->setPassword($username);
```

into the information I want to retrive, such as real name, email, my generated password etc, when I click the Login button for Facebook per say, I am asked again if I want to connect with my local testing site.

From what I understand, in the documentation I linked above, this :

```
$user = $this->userManager->findUserBy(array($this->getProperty($response) => $username));
```

is the line that checks if the user exists or not, and the initial code by itself, sets either **facebook_id** or **twitter_id** (this is how I save them) as a new **User** **username**. If I change the line

```
$user->setUsername($username); //same as facebook/twitter _id
```

into

```
$user->setUsername(setProperUsername()); //sets a proper unique username
```

Then everytime I try to login I get the "Register" message. So, I have a general idea of how it works but I am having a hard time understanding some things:

**1.** When I have registered with Facebook and I login with twitter, I register again, no knew row is created, but missing twitter_id fields are updated/populated, username stays intact. How come HWI/FOSUB knows I am the same person when my previous data were from Facebook not Twitter?

**2.** If there is a global way of knowing I am the same person, what data from the **$response** object should I use as a key to identify already registered users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing a lot with this, I have the answer if anyone runs into this type of situation

1. Check your **default_target** path, make it so it is **/profile**, **/account** etc, don't default to *login* again. Also, if a user is already logged in, do not make him access your *login* page. This **was** why my data was being updated. I was basically logged in with my Facebook account and registering with my Twitter account *too*.
2. **No**, there is no global way of knowing I am the same person. The **$response** object sent me a unique ID for that specific user according to the provider policy. You might use this to identify *already registered* users and log them in.